# How to calculate relative error of a random variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, coefficient-of-variation

This maybe a naive question, but I found two ways to calculate the relative error, one is common and another is from the papers I read.

Assume that the exact number is $n$, and the estimated number is $\tilde{n}$, the two ways to calculate the relative error are:

1) relative error = $\frac{n-\tilde{n}}{E[n]}$, which is the standard definition

2) relative error = $\frac{\sqrt{Var(\tilde{n})}}{n}$, which is the coefficient of variance (I read from a paper).

Now I am confused which one I should use, is there any corresponding scenario that these two formulas should be used?

PS: Please note that $n$ is a random variable.

Comment: The coefficient of variance/variation is defined as the ratio of standard deviation and mean of a random variable. Can you please explain why your formula in 2) looks different to this?

Comment: (2) is actually a measure of relative *precision,* not relative error, because it only incorporates variation in the estimate $\tilde n$ without accounting for a possible systematic difference between $\tilde n$ and $n$.

Comment: @MichaelMayer I made a mistake, and I have corrected it. Sitll, do you have some insights about these two formulas?

Comment: @whuber Someone told me that sine $n$ is a random variable, (1) is not applicable to estimate the relative error between $n$ and $\tilde{n}$, so (2) is used instead. I don't know if there is significant difference between relative _error_ and relative _precision_.

Comment: You have stated explicitly that $n$ is a number, not a random variable (which makes "$E(n)$" identical to $n$).  There is potentially a *huge* difference between relative error and relative precision.  One extreme is the estimate $\tilde{n}=0$, which has perfect relative precision and $-100\%$ relative error, but any unbiased estimator will exhibit a difference between the two measures.